# How to display mathematical symbols,physics,chemistry equations in android?

Tags: android, performance, mathjax, jqmath

I am developing a trivia quiz app which may have maths,physics and chemistry symbols, since this a real time game app everytime questions will be downloaded from a server and shown for particular topic.It needs to be a native android app and performance is very important(two player game).If I am using jqmath or mathml inside webview as mentioned it takes a bit of time to render, is there any other android library or should I use ndk c or c++ libraries for performance(if so kindly name them) or how can I improve performance with webview itself or any other better idea, please suggest?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an year, I found a library which could do this quite efficiently and have used this in current project. This is the link of that great work [Mathview](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView) which you can easily include in your native code itself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need a TeX-like system to generate mathematics/physics/chemistry symbol and/or equations? If that's so, [TeXLive4Android](https://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/) is worth a trial.

Or you might want to build a webservice that use TeX-like systems to generate png image, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310507/any-latex-web-services-with-an-api).